# Finding subspaces orthogonal to itself

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, orthogonality

given $\varphi((x_1, x_2)$,$(y_1, y_2)$) = $x_1y_1 − x_2y_2$ where $\varphi:\mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ how can i find the subspaces $W$ such that $W^\perp = W$ ?

Comment: Is is really $x_1y_{\color{red}1}-x_2y_1$?

Comment: ops its $y_2$ in the second

Comment: fixed it now @Bernard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Find a non-zero vector $(a,b)$ such that $\varphi \bigl((a,b),(a,b)\bigr)=0$ and take $W=\{\lambda(a,b)\mid\lambda\in\mathbb R\}$.

Comment: it was my first thought but does it gives me all subspaces? I have trouble seeing it

Comment: In this case, yes. Well, with one exception: $\{0\}$.

Comment: Ok! Thanks! but why in this case?

Comment: Because $\dim\mathbb R^2=2$ and $\mathbb R^2$ is not orthogonal to itself. So, a non-trivial subspace orthogonal to itself must have dimension $1$. And therefore it is of the form that I mentioned in my answer for same vector $(a,b)$ orthogonal to itself.